# getting the url of the page where the user is trying to go back to

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to determine the url of the page that the user is trying to go back to?For example if I am currently in:

http://site.com/forward and the previous page that I accessed before it is http://site.com how do I get the url http://site.com

```
window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {

    //get url
}
```

Is this possible in JavaScript?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with

```
document.referrer
```

([MDC docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.referrer); [DOM specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-95229140)) Hope it will help you..!!

This solution will not always work....for that there is an option of storing the URLs in cookies everytime before moving further...

Comment: +1 Easily a 95% solution. Note that it won't work if the user was on `http://site.com` and then *typed* `http://site.com/forward` into the browser address bar. But it will work if the user followed a link on `http://site.com` that took them to `http://site.com/forward`.

Comment: you are correct..for that there is an option of storing the URLs in cookies everytime before moving further..